# Magento: Remove Place (Review) Order Page in Standard Checkout (NOT OnePage Checkout)

Tags: magento, paypal, checkout, magento-1.6

I'm working on a project where the site only provides "Free Shipping".

I'n my standard page (NOT one page checkout), after coming from Paypal, customers still need to see the "Review Order" page. This page is unnecessary because we only have free shipping.

Is there a way to remove this page?

Thanks

Comment: It is possible, check out the 3rd comment here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7607180/magento-easy-way-to-remove-paypal-express-review-step