# Error while trying to remove paypal express review page from magento 1.8

Tags: php, magento, paypal, magento-1.8

Hello I have followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7607180/magento-easy-way-to-remove-paypal-express-review-step)! to remove the paypal express review page from my magento store

however when i am redirected to the placeOrder method
this line of code fails and generates a Mage_Core_Exception

```
$this->_checkout->place($this->_initToken())
```

then i am redirected to the order review page with the error message saying "Cusotmer Email is Required"

here's the stack trace

```
#0 /http/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Resource/Customer.php(76): Mage::exception('Mage_Customer', 'Customer email ...')
#1 /http/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php(1122): Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Customer->_beforeSave(Object(Mage_Customer_Model_Customer))
#2 /http/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(318): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract->save(Object(Mage_Customer_Model_Customer))
#3 /http/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Express/Checkout.php(942): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->save()
#4 /http/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Express/Checkout.php(549): Mage_Paypal_Model_Express_Checkout->_prepareNewCustomerQuote()
#5 /http/app/code/local/Mage/Paypal/Controller/Express/Abstract.php(324): Mage_Paypal_Model_Express_Checkout->place('EC-7FH153025J46...', 'freeshipping_fr...')
#6 /http/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Paypal_Controller_Express_Abstract->placeOrderAction()
#7 /http/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('placeOrder')
#8 /http/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#9 /http/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#10 /http/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#11 /http/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#12 {main}
```

If at this point i click on the shopping cart and go through the paypal checkout process again.. I am indeed able to complete the order and this exception is not thrown the second time around...

but it is always consistent the first time fails the second time goes through...

any help will be much appreciated

Comment: try this http://www.tall-paul.co.uk/2012/06/15/magento-email-address-when-using-paypal-express-in-1-6/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Magento: easy way to remove "paypal/express/review" step](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7607180/magento-easy-way-to-remove-paypal-express-review-step)