# Magento + PayPal express - user comes back without shipping method

Tags: php, magento, paypal

I have a Magento website with the PayPal express payment option. I'm trying to skip the review page when my costumers pay with PayPal. As was mentioned in a former thread ([Magento: easy way to remove "paypal/express/review" step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7607180/magento-easy-way-to-remove-paypal-express-review-step)), this can be easily achieved by writing an extension that changes a few line in the controller, and this behavior is actually built into v1.9.

However, these solutions didn't work for me. The built-in option apparently did nothing, and the review page was still there. The workarounds proposed in the former thread caused an infinite loop between the actions "placeOrder" and "review".

After a long time, I have now found out that when the user comes back from PayPal, the system doesn't recognize the shipping method selected in the PayPal checkout screen, and accordingly sends the user back to the review page to select a shipping method.

Has anyone ever encountered that or have any solution in mind? I am using Magento 1.9.1.0, and PayPal express is in sandbox mode.

Comment: I have the same problem. My conclusion so far is that the Quote is only saved after returning from PayPal, making the shipping option non-selectable at the time of return. Manually opening the /paypal/return URL again does select the shipping method, but that's hardly a solution.

Comment: Are you using Magento1.9? I'm no longer involved in that project I was doing, but perhaps this issue is addressed in Magento 2.0

Comment: Yes, 1.9. Can't just update to 2.0 at the moment... but I think I'll try a fresh 2.0 installation just to see if things work there.

Comment: I'd love to hear how that worked out for you.

Comment: This issue is also happening when using onestepcheckout by idev, an observer app/code/local/Idev/OneStepCheckout/Model/Observers/PaypalExpress.php was responsible in our case, maybe this will help someone.