# Magento paypal express review page and agreements

Tags: php, magento, paypal, review

at the moment i'm trying to commit a little change to Magento's Paypal Express Extension. I'm trying to get rid of the review page because it's unnecessary.

How it's done is alreasy described here:
[Magento: easy way to remove "paypal/express/review" step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7607180/magento-easy-way-to-remove-paypal-express-review-step)

But it won't work when you enable agreements. 
And here's the problem:

```
app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Controller/Express/Abstract.php
```

> line 314 to 316 must be uncommented

```
if (array_diff($requiredAgreements, $postedAgreements)) {
   Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('paypal')->__('Please agree to all the terms and conditions before placing the order.'));
}
```

```
app/code/community/Sandfox/RemovePaypalExpressReviewStep/etc/config.xml
```

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Sandfox_RemovePaypalExpressReviewStep>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Sandfox_RemovePaypalExpressReviewStep>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <sandfox_removepaypalexpressreviewstep>
                <class>Sandfox_RemovePaypalExpressReviewStep_Model</class>
            </sandfox_removepaypalexpressreviewstep>
            <paypal>
                <rewrite>
                    <config>Sandfox_RemovePaypalExpressReviewStep_Model_Config</config>
                </rewrite>
            </paypal>
        </models>
        <events>
            <controller_action_predispatch_paypal_express_review>
                <observers>
                    <sandfox_removepaypalexpressreviewstep>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>sandfox_removepaypalexpressreviewstep/observer</class>
                        <method>controllerActionPredispatchPaypalExpressReview</method>
                    </sandfox_removepaypalexpressreviewstep>
                </observers>
            </controller_action_predispatch_paypal_express_review>
        </events> 
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <paypal>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                         <Sandfox_RemovePaypalExpressReviewStep before="Mage_Paypal">Sandfox_RemovePaypalExpressReviewStep</Sandfox_RemovePaypalExpressReviewStep>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </paypal>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

Now i tried to rewrite the controller (is it really a controller? Why it's not in controllers  but has it's own Controller directory?)

```
app/code/community/Sandfox/RemovePaypalExpressReviewStep/Controller/Express/Abstract.php
```

```
    <?php
    include_once("Mage/Paypal/Controller/Express/Abstract.php");

    class Sandfox_RemovePaypalExpressReviewStep_Controller_Express_Abstract extends Mage_Paypal_Controller_Express_Abstract
    {

        public function placeOrderAction()
        {
            try {
            .
            .
            .
                //    if (array_diff($requiredAgreements, $postedAgreements)) {
                 //       Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('paypal')->__('Please agree to all the terms and conditions before placing the order.'));
                  //  }
                }       
            .
            .
            .       

}
```

At the moment the rewrite doesn't work. Can someone give me a hint?

tec:
Magento 1.9.2
PHP 5.5
MYSQL 5.6.19

Comment: Which version of Magento are you using?

Answer (score 0):

In your config.xml, remove the space after module's name

```
<Sandfox_RemovePaypalExpressReviewStep before="Mage_Paypal">Sandfox_RemovePaypalExpressReviewStep </Sandfox_RemovePaypalExpressReviewStep>
```

should be changed to

```
<Sandfox_RemovePaypalExpressReviewStep before="Mage_Paypal">Sandfox_RemovePaypalExpressReviewStep</Sandfox_RemovePaypalExpressReviewStep>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response Rakesh, but it didn't fix the problem.

Comment: Did you clear your cache after that? If yes, I suspect there must be something wrong in what you've missed to include in this question. Can you add complete config.xml file to the question?

Comment: Yes i cleared cache in Magento backend and directory var/cache. I Updated the config.xml above - now it's the complete file. I posted my technical einvironment specs. Thanks for your reponse

Answer (score 0):

You can't extends an Abstract class. U need to copy into local/Mage...